# Range error Java NanoHTTPD serving HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: java, http-live-streaming, m3u8, nanohttpd

Range error Java NanoHTTPD serving HTTP Live Streaming

I am trying to serve HLS Video stream using Java based NanoHTTPD HTTP server. I am also using VLC to play the .m3u8 file. Funny thing is VLC is able to play my video but NanoHTTPD is throwing "java.net.SocketException". I am using SimpleWebServer.java that ships with NanoHTTPD

Here is my .m3u8 file

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXTINF:10,
sample_320k-1.ts
#EXTINF:10,
sample_320k-2.ts
#EXTINF:10,
sample_320k-3.ts
#EXTINF:10,
sample_320k-4.ts
#EXTINF:11,
sample_320k-5.ts
#EXTINF:11,
sample_320k-6.ts
#EXTINF:11,
sample_320k-7.ts
#EXTINF:11,
sample_320k-8.ts
#EXTINF:10,
sample_320k-9.ts
#EXTINF:11,
sample_320k-10.ts
#EXTINF:11,
sample_320k-11.ts
#EXTINF:10,
sample_320k-12.ts
#EXTINF:10,
sample_320k-13.ts
#EXTINF:10,
sample_320k-14.ts
#EXTINF:10,
sample_320k-15.ts
#EXTINF:11,
sample_320k-16.ts
#EXTINF:9,
sample_320k-17.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Here is my console out from Eclipse
    Server started, Hit Enter to stop.

```
GET '/' 
  HDR: 'connection' = 'keep-alive'
  HDR: 'accept-language' = 'en-US,en;q=0.8'
  HDR: 'host' = '127.0.0.1:8080'
  HDR: 'accept' = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
  HDR: 'user-agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31'
  HDR: 'accept-encoding' = 'gzip,deflate,sdch'
  HDR: 'accept-charset' = 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'
GET '/favicon.ico' 
  HDR: 'connection' = 'keep-alive'
  HDR: 'accept-language' = 'en-US,en;q=0.8'
  HDR: 'host' = '127.0.0.1:8080'
  HDR: 'accept' = '*/*'
  HDR: 'user-agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31'
  HDR: 'accept-encoding' = 'gzip,deflate,sdch'
  HDR: 'accept-charset' = 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'
GET '/Http_Live_Streaming/vodhls/stream-local.m3u8' 
  HDR: 'connection' = 'close'
  HDR: 'host' = 'localhost:8080'
  HDR: 'range' = 'bytes=0-'
  HDR: 'icy-metadata' = '1'
  HDR: 'user-agent' = 'VLC/2.0.7 LibVLC/2.0.7'
GET '/Http_Live_Streaming/vodhls/sample_320k-1.ts' 
  HDR: 'connection' = 'close'
  HDR: 'host' = 'localhost:8080'
  HDR: 'range' = 'bytes=0-'
  HDR: 'icy-metadata' = '1'
  HDR: 'user-agent' = 'VLC/2.0.7 LibVLC/2.0.7'
java.net.SocketException
    at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.execute(NanoHTTPD.java:662)
    at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$1$1.run(NanoHTTPD.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
GET '/Http_Live_Streaming/vodhls/sample_320k-2.ts' 
  HDR: 'connection' = 'close'
  HDR: 'host' = 'localhost:8080'
  HDR: 'range' = 'bytes=0-'
  HDR: 'icy-metadata' = '1'
  HDR: 'user-agent' = 'VLC/2.0.7 LibVLC/2.0.7'
java.net.SocketException
    at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.execute(NanoHTTPD.java:662)
    at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$1$1.run(NanoHTTPD.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
GET '/Http_Live_Streaming/vodhls/sample_320k-3.ts' 
  HDR: 'connection' = 'close'
  HDR: 'host' = 'localhost:8080'
  HDR: 'range' = 'bytes=0-'
  HDR: 'icy-metadata' = '1'
  HDR: 'user-agent' = 'VLC/2.0.7 LibVLC/2.0.7'
java.net.SocketException
    at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.execute(NanoHTTPD.java:662)
    at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$1$1.run(NanoHTTPD.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
GET '/Http_Live_Streaming/vodhls/sample_320k-4.ts' 
  HDR: 'connection' = 'close'
  HDR: 'host' = 'localhost:8080'
  HDR: 'range' = 'bytes=0-'
  HDR: 'icy-metadata' = '1'
  HDR: 'user-agent' = 'VLC/2.0.7 LibVLC/2.0.7'
java.net.SocketException
    at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.execute(NanoHTTPD.java:662)
    at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$1$1.run(NanoHTTPD.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
java.net.SocketException
    at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.execute(NanoHTTPD.java:662)
    at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$1$1.run(NanoHTTPD.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
java.net.SocketException
    at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.execute(NanoHTTPD.java:662)
    at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$1$1.run(NanoHTTPD.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
java.net.SocketException
    at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.execute(NanoHTTPD.java:662)
    at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$1$1.run(NanoHTTPD.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Server stopped.
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of NanoHttpd are you using?  I might be that recent commits to the project have improved things for you, and in the support of the HTTP 1.1 protocol (that is, the "keep-alive" part of the connection handling).

I'd be curious to see if you run into issues with the latest (2.0.3) release of NanoHttpd.

In addition, I'll take a look at the way NanoHttpd is handling the "range" request - especially open-ended ranges like your stack trace indicates are being sent.

Thanks!